# fallo en la función sum

Tags: c++, punteros

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Adjunto el código.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

// Function prototype
int sum(const int *begin, const int *end);

// Test Driver
int main() {
int a[] = {8, 4, 5, 3, 2, 1, 4, 8};
cout << sum(a, a+8) << endl;        // a[0] to a[7]
cout << sum(a+2, a+5) << endl;      // a[2] to a[4]
cout << sum(&a[2], &a[5]) << endl;  // a[2] to a[4]
return 0;
}


int sum(const int *begin, const int *end) {
  int sum = 0;
  for (int i=0; begin < end;i++) {
    sum += *(begin+i);
  }
  return sum;
}
```

Alguien me puede decir que estoy haciendo mal en la función sum, para que me salga el error que os paso en la imagen? En principio al ser variables const mientras no las escribas no habría problema creo.

Comment: Creo que descubrí cual es el problema, es que la variable i crece indefinidamente, de manera que cuando voy a sumar begin+i apunta a zonas que no le corresponden. Hay alguna forma de saber o ver que rango de direcciones tiene mi proceso, asignado para saber en que punto el puntero se sale de zona. Gracias y soy novato.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
int sum(const int *begin, const int *end) {
  int sum = 0;
  for (int i=0; begin < end;i++) {
    sum += *(begin+i);
  }
  return sum;
}
```

Para salir del bucle estás comparando `begin` con `end` y ninguno de los dos cambia dentro del bucle... por lo que el mismo se va a repetir indefinidamente. Cambia `i` por un puntero:

```
int sum(const int *begin, const int *end) {
  int sum = 0;
  for (int* i=begin; i!=end; i++) {
    sum += *i;
  }
  return sum;
}
```